# jQuery xml reader - how to select a category and it's first 5 items

Tags: jquery, xml

How do I choose the "News" category from "section" in the following xml sample starting with:

```
$(feed).find('section').each(function () {
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<feed>
    <section category="News">
        <title>Recent News</title>
        <article>
            <headline lang="en">News headline here</headline>
            <url>#</url>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section category="Blog">
        <title>Recent Blogs</title>
        <article>
            <headline lang="en">Recent blog headline here</headline>
            <url>#</url>
        </article>
</section>
</feed>
```

Also, how do I choose just the first 5 articles?

```
$(this).find('article').each(function () {
    var headline = $(this).find('headline').text();
    var url = $(this).find('url').text();
    html += '<li><a href="' + url + '">' + headline + '</a></li>';
});
```

Comment: You have duplicated `</article>` and not closed `<feed>` in your xml - is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$(feed).find('section[category="News"]').each(...`
2. `$(this).find('article').slice(0,5).each(...`